# How decorator override members could be used in the decorable code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm trying to implement a kind of decorator pattern in Unity, but I am having problems.

I am trying to override one of the members from the interface using a decorator, but I noticed that the overridden implementation is only used inside the class and not in the decorable (which is sad but is perfectly reasonable).

My question is how could I do that. Here is an example of the problem (Take into account that I can't use constructors in Unity serializable objects if I want to show them in the inspector, that is why I am using generics).

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Testing testing;
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Testing : DecoratorC<Base> { } // Workaround to show in Inspector a generic class.
    void Start()
    {
        testing.Increase();
        testing.Amount++;
    }
}

public interface IBase
{
    void Increase();
    float Amount { get; set; }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Base : IBase
{
    public void Increase()
    {
        Amount++;
        Debug.Log("Increasing");
    }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
}

[System.Serializable]
public abstract class Decorator<T> : IBase where T : IBase
{
    public T decorable;
    public virtual float Amount { get => decorable.Amount; set => decorable.Amount = value; }
    public virtual void Increase() => decorable.Increase();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class DecoratorC<T> : Decorator<T> where T : IBase
{
    public override float Amount {
        get => base.Amount;
        set {            
            base.Amount = value;
            Debug.Log("Amount");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Increasing
Amount
```

While I want to get:

```
Amount
Increasing
Amount
```

It is my first time using a Decorator pattern so I thought that was how it works, but it doesn't and now I am not very sure how to do it.